# VR AR Toolkit for Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

One small question,
VR/AR tool kit is mainly developed for Unity.
Please give me some updates on Unreal Engine.

Does VR/AR toolkit also work for Unreal? If not then when we can expect its' arrival.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the AR/VR toolkit server requires a Unity plugin counterpart to parse the server responses, and at the moment there is no official plan to support Unreal Engine.

However, we provide an alternative solution for bringing Forge models to different platforms and environments: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils. This Node.js library/CLI tool converts Forge models into the [glTF](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/tree/master/specification/2.0) format which can then be loaded into Unity, Unreal Engine, and other targets as well.